# How the Windows MessageBox with message "Member not found." is generated? Is it possible to intercept it?

Tags: c++, windows, com, mfc, idispatch

I have an MFC-based Windows application with a GUI, it is written in C++ and has a lot of COM objects; let's call it "HelloWorld".

A user sent me a bug report: sometimes, in response to a particular
user action, a MessageBox shows up (in the following image I removed the title bar caption).

[image]

1) The title bar caption of the MessageBox is `HelloWorld` and, looking for that string in the code, it seems to me that the it is the resource string
identified by `AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE` (in the `.rc` source file of the
application); the
following is the relevant section of the `.rc` source file:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
   AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE       "HelloWorld"
   AFX_IDS_IDLEMESSAGE     "..."
   AFX_IDS_HELPMODEMESSAGE "..."
END
```

2) On a Windows 7 with English laguage the message of the MessageBox
is "Member not found."

3) In Windows 7 with different languages the message is translated in
the proper language.

I think that the problem is described here
 [HOWTO: Troubleshoot "Member Not Found" 0x80020003 Error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172108) and is related to the
`DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND` error; I actually solved the problem at the
user site.

But there is a different problem that is still unsolved and it is a
problem of user experience: the user who sent me the bug report is not
a programmer and does not know the meaning of "member" in expression
such as "member function" and so the user was slightly offended by the message because of the
many meanings of the word "member" (at least in English and in
Italian).

I checked the source code of the application and it seems to me that
the MessageBox is not generated by the application; now I would like
to know how that MessageBox is generated in order to intercept it and
display a different MessageBox: is it possible to do?

Comment: Seriously, are you really going to spend time on this?  Maybe you should just tell the user he shouldn't be worried about losing his "member;" I'm quite certain he has no trouble finding it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am serious.

Comment: So am I.  This is not something you should be spending your time on; this is something you should be blaming Microsoft for.  Anything is possible given enough time and money; the real question is, is it worth it, given that you've solved the problem already and it may never recur?

Comment: When the message appears, take a stack trace. That will tell you who is generating it.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you Raymond, I had that idea and launched Sysinternals' `procexp` at the user's site in order to have a look at the stacks traces of the threads. But `procexp` show me a message about a wrong version of `dbghelp.dll`, my available time for that issue was running out and so I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the specific error, but to suppress message box, this is the windows call.

```
BOOL SetThreadErrorMode(
  _In_   DWORD dwNewMode,
 _Out_  LPDWORD lpOldMode
);
```

Prior to windows 7, use SetErrorMode.

Comment: Won't that suppress all message boxes?